# Is there a way to know if pointer-events timestamps in chrome IOS is accurate than IOS native event with stylus pen?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, sdk, pointer-events, stylus-pen

I'm collecting points throught html canvas with javascript in Chrome IOS. I need to understand how pointer-event timestamp are generated and compared them to IOS native event timestamp.

In Chrome IOS the frame rate is around 60 fps and there is less generated pointer events that IOS SDK native event (it used device frame rate). I've tried to use coalescedEvents() to know how timestamps are computed, it seems that Chrome aggregate multiple events in one.

I expect that Chrome IOS pointer-event timestamps should be genereted like native device events.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium iOS is open source now, I invite you to dig into the sources and find out yourself as your questions it too specific.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/ios/